# How to replace -a- with <a> where a can be anything

Tags: javascript, regex

In JS, I want to replace `-a-`, with `<a>` and `-b-` with `<b>` and `-c-` with `<c>` and so on... So the regex would be something like this:

```
-(variable)-
```

should be replaced with:

```
<(variable)>
```

How to achieve this in JS?

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: What about `- a -`? What about `1 - 2 = -2` ?

Comment: try to do it first, then edit your question to add your code so we can help you

Comment: Yes, but I can't find a solution. Maybe I don't use the right search tags, but I hope someone at stackoverflow knows the answer

Comment: If you tried anything, a glimpse at your code might help us understand what you are trying to achieve further than what an explanation as simple as this one can help. Also this website is not for us doing code for you, keep that in mind.

Comment: **DON'T** add solution/answer in question. If you've it before someone adds it, feel free to add it as answer even on your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a *capture group*, which you can then use as a substitution:

```
"-a-".replace(/-(.)-/g, "<$1>"); // <a>
```

There, the `(` and `)` define the capture group, the `.` inside means "any one character here" (adjust as necessary, perhaps `.+`), and in the replacement string, `$1` means "the value of the first capture group."

Comment: doesn't work at https://myregextester.com/ and http://www.regexe.com/ Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The above works, so...presumably, yes.

Comment: I forget to remove the `/` and `/g` , it works fine!

Comment: `.*` => `.+`. I guess OP don't want `--` to be replaced as `<>`.

Comment: @Tushar: :-) I dare say you're right...